# Testing websites on Windows Phone 7

Tags: internet-explorer

My company has made the decided to start testing our sites on a multitude of devices e.g. iPhones, Android, Windows and assorted tablets. They've tasked me with finding the largest common denominator.

Which Windows phones would give us the largest spectrum of the market in terms of compatibility?

Answer (score 7):

The browser is the same in all browsers regardless.  You can get the results you want simply by installing the developer tools and using the emulator.  No hardware required.  The thing you want to watch out for is 7.0 (wp original), 7.1 sdk (wp75 mango) versus wp8.0.

Comment: If you were to choose a device which would it be?

Comment: I would see what is cheapest based on my cellphone plan and carrier.
My -favorite- devices are HTC Titan II and Nokia 900. I'm USA based.
Non-USA options may be different. Some sharp looking phones out there.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the results are the same. Performance wise your site might be completely unusable on a low-end device like the Lumia 610.

Comment: I'd also point out that you cannot test pinch/zoom without real hardware...